# Action bars title´s text color

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I don´t know what Im doing wrong but I can´t change Action bar´s text color. I am using AppCompat and I want to put text white. There are my styles if someone can help me. Thank you.

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>


</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>

</style>


<style name="MyActionBarTitleText"
       parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing MyActionBarTitleText parent style to TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title

refer to:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText

Answer (score 0):

you can place the "actionMenuTextColor" attribute under the "Theme.Example" style tag and try again